# How to select div contains parent div attr?

Tags: jquery

I try to select `img` in `.sub rel='0'` and trigger click, looks like `$('.sub[rel=0] img').trigger('click')` , but it does't work. 
What is wrong with this selector code `$('.sub[rel=0] img')`

Thanks!

```
<div class="sub" rel="0">
    <img>
</div>
<div class="sub" rel="1">
    <img>
</div>
```

**Update**

```
function geturlvars(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
return vars;
};

realid = geturlvars()["id"]
function checkstate(){
    if(realid){
        $('.sub[rel=realid] img').trigger('click');
    }
    $('.sub[rel=realid] img').click(function(){
        console.log('hi');
    });
};
checkstate();
```

Comment: You're missing a `.` in front of `sub` to designate a class

Comment: `sub` is a class so you need a  `.` in front of it to reference it.  `$('.sub[rel=0] img')`

Comment: sorry it's typo but in my demo had `.`

Comment: Did you try it ? It works.

Comment: Did you remember to wrap that in `$(document).ready() { ... });`

Comment: Do you have a click handler for the image like `$(".sub[rel=0]").click(function(){...})` ?

Comment: [Works here](http://jsfiddle.net/ursW3/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing seems to be wrong with that situation...

html:

```
<div class="sub" rel="0">
 <img>
</div>
<div class="sub" rel="1">
 <img>
</div>​
```

js:

```
console.log($('.sub[rel=0] img')[0]);​
```

console:

```
<img>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PHrRY/

**moreover**

Here is an example where there is a triggered click event. For you to trigger a click event on that image, it must have an attached event. More than likely if there is no event, nothing happens, and that is why your trigger is not actually firing an event off. This code will fire the event using `trigger`.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PHrRY/1/

**edit**

Here is an example where the `0` for rel is stored in a variable:

summary: 
`var relNumber = "0 0";
console.log($('.sub[rel="'+relNumber+'"] img')[0]);`

http://jsfiddle.net/PHrRY/3/

The extra `"` quotation marks are used in case there is a space inside of the `relNumber`.

**In response to update**

this code should be

```
if(realid){
    $('.sub[rel="'+realid+'"] img').trigger('click');
}
$('.sub[rel="'+realid+'"] img').click(function(){
    console.log('hi');
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, actually in my code is a variable in rel, it is $('.sub[rel=variable] img')

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

```
$(".sub[rel=0]").click(function(){ alert("Click Triggered!");  })

     function geturlvars(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    } return vars; };

realid = geturlvars()["id"] function checkstate(){

    realid = "0";  // delete this
    if(realid){
        $('.sub[rel='+realid+'] img').trigger("click");
    }
         }; 
checkstate(); ​
```

Make sure the click function is a global function and categorize the variables from the text

```
$('.sub[rel=realid] img')        // Wrong
$('.sub[rel='+realid+'] img')    // Correct
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/javascript/T7uss/

Comment: Thanks for help, this remind me `click()` should write before trigger!!

Comment: @user1775888 give me a few

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if they are necessary, but I am always using `"` when I want to select a value from an attribute:

```
$('.sub[rel="0"] img');
           -^-^-
```

Maybe this does the trick.

Comment: This shouldn't matter as long as there are no spaces.